# setUndecorated(true) to a JDialog created from an instance of JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

I currently have a `JDialog` created by calling the `createDialog()` method from my instance of `JOptionPane`:

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(myPanel, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[]{}, null);
dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "");
```

I wanted to be able to remove the title bar from the `JDialog` by calling `setUndecorated(true)` onto the `JDialog`, but I get an `IllegalComponentStateException: The dialog is displayable` exception when I attempt to run my program.

As far as I know, the dialog is not being displayed before I call `dialog.show()`, which leads me to believe that the dialog is indeed "displayable" upon instantiating the dialog through `pane.createDialog()` far beyond my understanding of the `JDialog` API.

I have attempted to call `setVisible(false)` prior to using `setUndecorated(true)`, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated as to how or of it is possible at all to remove the title bar of a `JDialog` of this type. Removing the title bar from a normal `JDialog` is easy enough, as seen from numerous other answers to questions of this type, but I cannot seem to get it to work for a `JDialog` created through `createDialog()`.

Relevant code:

```
            input= new JTextField(50);

        input.addKeyListener(new ConsoleKeyListener());


        input.addAncestorListener( new RequestFocusListener() );
        field = new JTextArea();
        field.setEditable(false);
        field.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane area = new JScrollPane(field, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        field.setRows(10);
        field.setText(consoleText);
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

        myPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
        myPanel.add(input, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        myPanel.add(area, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        input.setFocusable(true);
        input.requestFocus();
        int result = 101;
        //int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, myPanel,"", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);
        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(myPanel, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[]{}, null);

        dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "");
        dialog.setVisible(false);
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);
        //dialog.undecorated = true;


        //dialog.setOpacity(0.55f);
        removeMinMaxClose(dialog);
        removeMinMaxClose(pane); 
        removeMinMaxClose(myPanel);
        dialog.getRootPane().setOpaque(false);

        //JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        //dialog.setVisible(false);
        //dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        //myPanel.setUndecorated(true);
        //dialog.setUndecorated(true);
        //dialog.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);  
        //dialog.setBounds( 100, 100, 300, 200 );  
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.out.println("yo");
            }
        });
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to read the [JavaDoc entry on Component#isDisplayable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isDisplayable%28%29), then have a look at the source code for create dialog

> *"A component is made displayable either when it is added to a displayable containment hierarchy or when its containment hierarchy is
>   made displayable. A containment hierarchy is made displayable when its
>   **ancestor window is either packed** or made visible."*

Basically the dialog is packed as part of the `createDialog` method

**Possible solution**

A possible solution is to create your own dialog...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestOptionPane11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestOptionPane11();
    }

    public TestOptionPane11() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JDialog dialog = new JDialog((Frame)null, "Boo");

                JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane("Look ma, no hands", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                op.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        String name = evt.getPropertyName();
                        if ("value".equals(name)) {

                            dialog.dispose();

                        }
                    }
                });

                dialog.setUndecorated(true);
                dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                dialog.add(op);
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the JavaDoc reference and excellent explanation. Your solution helped me create a very believable console.