# JPanel for user input should show on top of all other windows

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, joptionpane, always-on-top

I am new to java swing and have a question, but first let me explain what my app does:

on first start my java web start application asks the user for username and password and stores them with java preferences api, afterwards (and for all other starts) it processes everything in background without any gui except if an error occure

How I am actually doing it:

```
public boolean getLogin() {
    JTextField u = new JTextField(5);
    u.setText("Username");
    JPasswordField p = new JPasswordField(5);
    p.setText("example");
    p.setEchoChar('*');

    JPanel input = new JPanel();
    input.setLayout(new BoxLayout(input, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    input.add(new JLabel("Please input your credentials"));
    input.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(25));
    input.add(u);
    input.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    input.add(p);

    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, input, "Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        id.setCredentials(u.getText(), p.getPassword());
        return true;
    } else
        return false;

}
```

Works like a charm, only problem I have is that the JOptionPane sometimes appear behind all other windows like webbrowser, explorer, etc. Is there a solution for JOptionPane/JPanel to let the window appear on top of all others? Or is JOptionPane/JPanel the wrong thing? I dont need a "always on top" solution, just that the window appears on top of all others.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'll have to create your own `JDialog` and use `setAlwaysOnTop` or call `bringFront`

Comment: wow that was a fast answer ... 30 seconds ... so there is really no other option on doing this?

Comment: I "think" I might have done something about this a while ago, but I'm having a hard time find the answer, but it is generally the cleanest ;)

Comment: Okay then thank you very much for this instantly answer :)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100587/setundecoratedtrue-to-a-jdialog-created-from-an-instance-of-joptionpane/17100642#17100642) isn't exactly the same, but would give you a solution that could still use `JOptionPane`...