# Frameless AND modal JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I would like to create a modal AND frameless dialog window with least implementation overhead possible.

I cannot just dialog.setUndecorated(false) if the dialog was created with a non-null parent window that is already displayed (see  [setUndecorated(true) to a JDialog created from an instance of JOptionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100587/setundecoratedtrue-to-a-jdialog-created-from-an-instance-of-joptionpane)).

The question is: can I do that in Swing at all? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Ok, Stackoverflow, I've found it:
http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/2005/09/making-a-custom-frameless-window/

Question is closed.

Comment: You can just create your own `JDialog`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? `JDialog d = new JDialog(parent, "title", true); d.setUndecorated(false);` doesn't work

Comment: The answer over there already explains how to fix it (make your own JDialog). The issue applies mainly to JOptionPane.

Comment: Please don't just edit in a link 'answer' to the question. If the link answered your question, the best practice is to post the relevant bits as an answer to your own question. If you find a duplicate on this site, you can flag your own question as a duplicate. Both answering and linking can provide value if it helps other people find the answer or avoid their own misunderstandings. If you feel that others won't benefit from learning from your experience, you can delete your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setUndecorated(true) to a JDialog created from an instance of JOptionPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100587/setundecoratedtrue-to-a-jdialog-created-from-an-instance-of-joptionpane)

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot just dialog.setUndecorated(false)

That's because you want:

```
d.setUndecorated(true);
```